# unix command to rename a group of files and take part of the name out

Tags: unix, command

I have a bunch of files in a dir. I need to rename all of them with part of the name taken out. EXAMPLE:

old:

```
64sdfdf2_test.txt363qww6.dat.z
64cvxc65_test.txt36ntg44.dat.z
6jtyjj54_test.txt3as3463.dat.z
```

new:

```
64sdfdf2363qww6.dat.z
64cvxc6536ntg44.dat.z
6jtyjj543as3463.dat.z
```

NOTE: "_test.txt" is what i need remove and it is the same in all the files.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *_test.txt*
do
new_name=`echo $i|sed 's/\(.*\)_test.txt\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
mv $i $new_name
done
```

i tested only the sed part and its working fine:

```
> echo "64sdfdf2_test.txt363qww6.dat.z" | sed 's/\(.*\)_test.txt\(.*\)/\1\2/g'
64sdfdf2363qww6.dat.z
```

Answer (score 0):

See the manpage for mmv. Something like

```
mmv '*_test.txt*' '#1#2'
```

should do the trick.